# Local React build works but Error 404 on the server build js css files. How to get parcel to build the paths correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, parcel

I'm trying to get a React app to work on a subdirectory on a hosted server. (I'm not using create-react-app)

My package.json file has the correct "homepage" path to my base react app home directory, however when I build the app with Parcel the directory of the assets in the index.html and some of the gif references inside App.00e499ed.js are not updated to the correct path (it just puts App.00e499ed.js) without any of the right structure (/react/thing/App.00e499ed.js) and therefore I get 404 errors when I upload it to the server and run it. I am now just searching these out and replacing them by hand but what am I missing in the build steps to be able do this automatically??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `homepage: "."` in `package.json` and build and deploy in any sub directory.

Comment: It does not... same result!?

Comment: This did not solve the issue at all. We need more details

Comment: Worked for me. Just add it in your package.json file under version.